# Elements not styling in external stylesheet using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a full page background color. Bootstrap does not apply the styles I'm specifying to an element.

This is my HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- bootstrap requirements and custom css + jquery -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- google fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid bg">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my CSS:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

/* font declaration */
body {
    font-family: Montserrat;
}

.bg {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("img/home-bg.jpg");

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%; 

    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

the html, body and body tag works fine. I can see them functioning when I inspect element on chrome. But the .bg class doesn't. The attributes work when I use it as an internal and inline stylesheet, but when I use it as external it doesn't. All of the stuff I am reading here just doesn't work.

I tried

```
div.bg {
     /* elements */
}

html > body > .bg {
     /* elements */
}
```

I tried adding container-fluid

```
.container-fluid.bg {
     /* elements */
}

body > div > .container-fluid > .bg {
     /* elements */
}
```

they all don't work

Comment: Your code is fine. Do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Could be a cache issue. Try hard-refresh or actually loading the CSS file via browser to check if code is different..

Comment: @Aziz I did the hard refresh several times, still no luck

Comment: @MichaelCoker welp, this fixed it. I got an Error 404 on the image because I set up the wrong directory